# Will Ubuntu speed up this laptop?

Tags: windows, laptop

Old s****y 2004 laptop, Intel core, weak, virus filled. I want to completely wipe the drive and upgrade to Ubuntu. I do not have any data I want to save, this computer was a hand me down that's been stashed in the drawer for almost a year. Not planning on anything heavier than internet browsing.

I have a gaming setup as well so I'm not worried if this fails, it's just a side project to take up spare time.

Also, doesn't Ubuntu have an install option which allows you to completely wipe the drive and  install? Because if so that's what I want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: It could. The setup does have an option to use the entire disk.

Answer (score 4):

Lubuntu should work well, it's a low ram version of Ubuntu that works well with older hardware.
And yes the installer will let you do a full disk install, which means it wipes anything that is already on the disk.